# drag and drop with core data

Tags: ios, objective-c

The code below implements drag and drop functionality in a table view. As you can see it accomplishes reordering by removing the object from an array (dataList) at a certain index and then positions it at the desired index.  This code doesn't use core data. My question is, how would you achieve this using core data. For example, would you continue using an array as in the code below and then save the array to core data and you try to retrieve and order the objects from core data according to the order in the array. Or would you reorder the objects directly in the core data store? if the latter, how?

```
#pragma mark Row reordering
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath 
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSString *item = [[dataList objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [dataList removeObject:item];
    [dataList insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [item release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a similar behavior by storing the order information in the coredata object. Let's call it `position`.

By this you are able to pass all your objects as an `NSArray` ordered by `NSSortDescriptor` with the property `position`.

After a drag&drop happened, make sure you **update** the position properties of the changed items accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sample code would be greatly appreciated if you have any.

Comment: http://www.timisted.net/blog/archive/core-data-drag-drop/  (Worked for me, though with some modernization)  This works for an otherwise unordered bag of objects that the user can order to their liking.  Would be interesting to see if it was possible to reorder an ordered relationship using drag-n-drop...

Comment: @stevesliva the project you linked to isn't done with ios, not sure if the drag and drop methods are implemented in ios. anyways, like I said, the project I link to in comment directly above this implements it in ios